# How much time is allowed and what kind of task is allowed in NSURLSessionDelegate in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

Do you how much time is allowed when the OS calls methods of `NSURLSessionDelegate` and `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` when the app crashed or is suspended using a background NSURLSession.

Do you know if I can perform the following actions inside  `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:`

- Core data request
- Save 1GB video in library
- Synchronous network request

I didn't find information in iOS documentation about this.

Thanks

Comment: My question does not concern what the background session downloads. I would like to know what I can do inside the delegate.

Comment: Ah, then do whatever you want. I suspect that you have a limited amount of time before you have to call the completion handler that your app delegate received (probably the standard three minutes, but I have to confess I haven't tested this particular aspect; you should test it). But other than that, I think you're fine.